# Invalid timestamp on Dwolla payment form

Tags: dwolla

My form is currently like this:

```
<form action="https://www.dwolla.com/payment/pay" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="[redacted]">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="[redacted]">
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="[redacted]">
    <input type="hidden" name="timestamp" value="1347696587496">
    <input type="hidden" name="callback" value="http://127.0.0.1:3000/donate/dwolla">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://127.0.0.1:3000/credits">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="destinationId" value="812-726-7978">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.25">
    <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="donation credit">
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="donation credit">
    <!-- amount input and submit button -->
</form>
```

Using node.js, I create my signature like so (note that I do not use any order ids):

```
dwolla.signature.create = function(timestamp) {
  return crypto
    .createHmac('sha1', dwolla.secret)
    .update(dwolla.key)
    .update('&')
    .update(timestamp.getTime().toString())
    .update('&')
    .digest('hex')
}

var timestamp = new Date()
var signature = dwolla.signature.create(timestamp)
```

Now when I click submit, I get a callback at the following address: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/credits?error=failure&error_description=Invalid+timestamp.` This means that at least my key/secret is valid and so is my signature, but my timestamp isn't.

What is wrong with my timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript time is in milliseconds not seconds -_-